# unable to update the list item in nested if-else condition in Visual Studio State Machine Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, workflow-activity, state-machine

I am working on State Machine Workflow using Visual Studio 2010 Workflow.

I want to update the list item on item changed. But unable to update the item. I am updating the item in nested If-Else condition. I am using Declarative Rule Condition.

Please Refer the code below and Workflow Image:

```
private void onManagerTaskChanged_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (onManagerTaskChanged_AfterProperties1.ExtendedProperties[workflowProperties.TaskList.Fields["Status"].Id].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == "SENT FOR CORRECTION")
            {


            }
            else if (onManagerTaskChanged.AfterProperties.ExtendedProperties[workflowProperties.TaskList.Fields["Status"].Id].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == "APPROVED")
            {
                if (workflowProperties.Item["Planning Status"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == "IN PROGRESS" || workflowProperties.Item["Mid Review Status"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == "COMPLETED" && workflowProperties.Item["Final Status"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == "IN PROGRESS")
                {
                    //WriteLog("Condition is true.");
                    workflowProperties.Item["Planning Status"] = "Approved";
                    workflowProperties.Item.SystemUpdate();
                }
                else if (workflowProperties.Item["Mid Review Status"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == "IN PROGRESS")
                {
                    workflowProperties.Item["Mid Review Status"] = "Completed";
                    workflowProperties.Item.SystemUpdate();
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[image: Workflow Error]

I am unable to update the list item in Second if-else. I can update the list item in First if-Else or outside of Second if-Else.

In short I want to update "Approved" in Planning Status column but cant update.

Please help. Its very urgent.

- Khan Abubakar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using if-else in wrong way. I was checking if-else in nested way like:

```
      if
    {
       // first if-else
    }
    else // first if-else
    {
      if
      {
          // second if-else
      }
      else // second if-else
      {
      }
    }
```

but actually above should be like:

```
if
{
   // first if-else
}
else // first if-else
{
}
if
{
    // second if-else
}
else // second if-else
{
}
```

In the above question I have used "Declarative code condition".
but now using "code condition" and found it is working. If it will be written in "Declarative code condition" then also it will work.